# Dangers of Upgrading from Laravel 5.7.4 to Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, upgrade, laravel-8, laravel-upgrade

I would like to know what the possibility is that when I upgrade from Laravel 5.7.4 to Laravel 8 that something in my website will break? If so what would the best approach be to upgrade to the newest version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way is to upgrade step by step, first to laravel 6, then 6->7 and lastly 7->8, you might also need to update your php version.
For each step there is an upgrade guide in the official docs. 
You will also have to check if all the composer packages are available for laravel8!

Comment: Thank you for the response, it seems that I might have some work ahead of me